# regx for taking strings under particular heading(till a blank line)

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this

```
Heading_1:
   content1
   content2
   ...
   ...

Heading_2:
  content1
  content2
  ....

Heading_x:
  content1
  content2
  ....
  ...
  contentn

Heading_n:
  ........
  ........
```

I have to take all the strings under headingx(till the blank line comes) that is content1 to contentn.
I tried like this

"((?s)headingx:.*\s*([^\n]*))"

But it's not working

Comment: What does _it's not working_ mean? Do you get any hits at all? Do you get an error? You need to help us a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a positive lookahead to check the string is followed by a blank line.

```
(?s)Heading_[^:]*:[^\\n]*\\n(.*?)(?=\\n\\n)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/6)

If you want the content of last Heading also(which is not followed by a blank line) then you need add a `$` inside the lookahead.

```
(?s)Heading_[^:]*:[^\\n]*\\n(.*?)(?=\\n\\n|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/9)

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)` DOTALL modifer which makes dot to match even new line character also.
- `Heading_[^:]*:[^\\n]*\\n` This matches only the Heading line including the new line character.
- `(.*?)(?=\\n\\n)` Following any character is captured until a blank line is reached. If a newline character is immediately followed by another new line character then it must be a blank line.

Comment: `I have to take all the strings under headingx(till the blank line comes)` so he don't want the last..

Comment: This will take all the strings together. What if I want to take strings one by one (till blank line) under the heading.

Comment: so you want to capture from content 1 to content n without newline character?

Comment: I want to capture one content at a time.